# How to wrap item from loop into element with concatenation?

Tags: php, loops, concatenation

I'm trying to push some items from loops to get a string of characters.

I have an `$liste_mots` array:

```
  0 => 
    array (size=5)
      'mot' => 
        array (size=7)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              'mot' => string 'My'
              'start' => float 0
              'end' => float 1 
          1 => 
            array (size=5)
              'mot' => string 'Name'  
              'start' => float 2
              'end' => float 3         
      'ID' => float 1

1 => 
    array (size=5)
      'mot' => 
        array (size=7)
          0 => 
            array (size=5)
              'mot' => string 'Is'
              'start' => float 4
              'end' => float 5 
          1 => 
            array (size=5)
              'mot' => string 'Zooboo' 
              'start' => float 6
              'end' => float 7        
      'ID' => float 2
```

What I'm trying to have, is something like that:

```
<div id='1'><span data-start='0' data-end='1'>My</span><span data-start='2' data-end='3'>Name</span></div><div id='2'><span data-start='4' data-end='5'>Is</span><span data-start='6' data-end='7'>Zooboo</span></div>
```

I did that:

```
$response = "";
      foreach ($liste_mots as $key => $item) {
             $response  = "<div id='" . $item['ID'] . "'>";
                foreach ($liste_mots[$key]['mot'] as $idx => $itm) {
                    $response .= "<span data-start='".$itm['start']."' data-end='".$itm['end']."'>" . $itm['mot'] . "</span></div>";
                }
            }
var_dump($response); die;
```

but with a `var_dump`, I have just the last `div` without `span` into...

Where am I wrong?

Comment: Could you paste the output of `var_export($liste_mot)` so can we can work on that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're resetting `$response` each time through the outer loop. You need to use concatenation there, just like you do in the inner loop. You also need to end the `div` in the outer loop, not after each `span` in the inner loop.

```
$response = "";
foreach ($liste_mots as $key => $item) {
    $response .= "<div id='" . $item['ID'] . "'>";
    foreach ($liste_mots[$key]['mot'] as $idx => $itm) {
        $response .= "<span data-start='".$itm['start']."' data-end='".$itm['end']."'>" . $itm['mot'] . "</span>";
    }
    $response .= "</div>";
}
var_dump($response); die;
```

Comment: I've already tried that but var_dump returns me : `string '' (length=0)`

Comment: That can only happen if `$liste_mots` is empty.

Comment: Make sure you have error reporting enabled. You may have mistyped a variable somewhere.

Comment: In this example `$liste_mots` is not empty but in my code, sometimes,  `$liste_mots[$key]['mot']` is empty...

Comment: I don't see any way that this code can return an empty `$response` if `$list_mots` is not empty.

Comment: Can you please change the question to use `var_export($list_mots)` so we can try testing the code?

Comment: I apologize... put my var_dump not on a good place... All works fine ! thanks all !

Answer (score 1):

you are closing div in wrong loop it should like this

```
$response = "";
foreach ($liste_mots as $key => $item) {
    $response  .= "<div id='" . $item['ID'] . "'>";
        foreach ($liste_mots[$key]['mot'] as $idx => $itm) {
            $response .= "<span data-start='".$itm['start']."' data-end='".$itm['end']."'>" . $item['mot'] . "</span>";
        }
    $response  .= "</div>";
}
var_dump($response); die;
```

Comment: I've already tried that but var_dump returns me : `string '' (length=0)`